# Pregunta marcada como duplicada, pero me parece que en este caso no debe ser así

Tags: discusión, duplicados-exactos

Ayer el usuario @Juan Sandoval [realizó una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300541) con un título un poco desafortunado porque entre el título y el contenido no había relación.

El título en cuestión era:

> ¿Cómo funcionan las promesas en javascript?

Pero en el enunciado preguntaba lo siguiente:

> Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current run of the JavaScript event loop.
>
> fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
>
> ¿A que se refiere con eso de que los callbacks adheridos a una promesa no serán ejecutados antes de que se complete la ejecución actual del event loop? No entiendo muy bien esa parte

Por lo que fue marcada como duplicada [de esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64265) por algunos usuarios.

Noté el problema y le recomendé a Juan, como usuario nuevo en el sitio, variar el título y remover algo que decía al final de la pregunta preguntando por opiniones de por qué se consideraban mejores que los `callbacks` ya que de esto hay suficiente contenido en el sitio y en Internet en general.

Ahora noto, que incluso después de su edición, ha seguido siendo marcada como duplicada por otros usuarios, pero en la pregunta a la que se hace referencia, aunque son increíbles las respuestas que hay allí, con inmensa cantidad de contenido y detallada explicación, no se cubre esta parte específica explicando qué es el bucle de eventos y cómo son tratadas las promesas dentro de este. Solo hay un pequeño comentario en la respuesta marcada como correcta que dice lo siguiente:

> Si necesitas entender a detalle cómo funciona la VM y el EventLoop, te recomiendo mucho ver [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyUFheng6J0&list=WL&index=6) de la conferencia JSFOO del año ante pasado.

Este vídeo es muy bueno, y siempre lo he recomendado, pero la explicación específica de lo que pregunta el usuario, aunque está contenida en partes dentro del vídeo, no está respondida en la pregunta en sí.

Por lo que mi pregunta es, ¿es válido marcar una pregunta como duplicada de otra, aunque en la otra no se responda esa pregunta pero haya referencia a un vídeo, que aunque tampoco responda la pregunta en sí, si se ve completo se podría llegar a entender lo que se ha preguntado en un inicio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considero que tienes razón y he re-abierto la pregunta, la pregunta es sobre cómo funciona una Promesa desde el punto de vista de la máquina virtual, que es un detalle específico de lo que es y cómo funciona una Promesa. Hay ya varias preguntas sobre promesas y asincronía en Javascript y, aunque todas están relacionadas, no se puede abarcar en detalle todo los casos en una única pregunta (sería demasiado amplia).

Comment: ¿ No podría ser marcada como **pregunta afín** de modo que el OP y quienes buscan explicaciones similares puedan encontrar algo que les ayude a orientarse mientras aparece una **respuesta canónica** ?

Comment: Hay varias respuestas *canónicas* sobre javascript y la asíncronía. Yo en esta he puesto un comentario enlazando una relacionada

Comment: Mi pregunta apunta a la situación general. No a tu pregunta o comentario específicos. Pues me parece que en los casos en que la pregunta del OP está siendo marcada como duplicada sin que la referencia brinde una respuesta precisa, se debiera marcar como afín para brindar la misma referencia sin el riesgo de anularla (o castigarla).

Comment: Eso requiere una nueva funcionalidad que no tenemos. Se podría pedir, pero en general para eso están las etiquetas.

Answer (score 2):

No es un duplicado de Promesas en eso estamos de acuerdo, pero si de como funcionan los **`callbacks`**, que explica magistralmente nuestros gurus [@devconcept](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2224/devconcept) y [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) en esta pregunta:

> [¿Qué diferencias hay entre callbacks, promises y async/await?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await)

Comment: En mi opinión, tampoco el tema está cubierto allí. Un callback puede ser asíncrono o síncrono pero será tratado de manera diferente por el bucle de eventos de la máquina virtual que si se tratara de una promesa. Creo que para explicarlo mejor se debería crear dos ejemplos asíncronos, uno usando callbacks y otro usando promesas para que se entienda que los callbacks son llamados en el mismo ciclo a diferente de los callbacks de las promesas.

Comment: lee la explicacion de asincronia de devconcept, nos dice donde queda el evento mientras tu codigo se ejecute, un callback al final es una funcion que pasas por parametros y lo ejecutas en otro contexto

Comment: Sí, lo leí, básicamente lo que explica es lo mismo que dice la referencia: _Lo que significa en realidad asincronía es la capacidad de ejecutar instrucciones en una etapa diferente del ciclo de eventos o event loop como se le conoce en inglés_. Pero alguien ha preguntado _qué significa lo anterior_. Después la pregunta explica un poco más pero no profundiza (sitúa un enlace) y alguien se puede quedar en las mismas. Como dice @PabloLozano, hay muchas respuestas en el sitio, y muchas geniales, pero ninguna explica esto de manera sencilla para que alguien que no sepa lo que es lo pueda entender.